# dot net core api with CORS still rejecting request

Tags: javascript, .net-core

I've got a dot net core API running on localhost:5000. 
I've added

```
services.AddCors();
```

to the ConfigureServices method, and

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
```

to the Configure method in StartUp.

I've got a js client that is attempting

```
return fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/Authorization', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  UserName: userName,
  Password: password,
})}).then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {return responseJson.userIsAdmin});
}
```

But when that last is executed, the browser refuses, saying:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Research points to the solutions already implemented in API project noted above. What am I missing?

Comment: In your `StartUp.cs`, where do have the Add/UseCors, before or after the Add/UseMvc? It needs to be before.

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 500”* ⬅ that’s the only important part of the message cited in the question. It’s not a CORS error; it only looks like one only because the server doesn’t add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to 500 error responses—it probably only adds it to 2xx success responses. So that 500 indicates you’re not having a CORS problem at all but instead some server-side failure. That’s the actual problem you need to identify the cause of & fix: The server’s saying there’s some fatal error—server-side failure—and it has stopped working completely, become unavailable

Comment: http://abusanad.net/2018/09/17/fetch-data-using-javascript-from-asp-net-core-localhost/

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting to a specific origin: `builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")`, this means the request origin of your app can only be http://localhost:3000, and then allowing any origin.

Start with the least amount of CORS restrictions and work from there:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
```

See [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the flag to the controller as well? Add the `EnableCors` flag to your Authorization controller.

```
[EnableCors]
public class AuthorizationController
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for me was the combination of one of the comments and one of the answers.  To solve problem"

1 - Fix the system error causing “**The response had HTTP status code 500**” as sideshowbarker stated (thank you).  In my case, I temporarily enabled static files in webapi and put the my web pages in wwwroot.  This was I avoiding CORS altogether Additionally, I would have caught the 500 error sooner if I had only paid attention to the DEBUG CONSOLE and noticed the stack track that was flowing by.

2 - After fixing the cause of the 500 error and turning off static files, I had to changed my app.UseCors code section to match Brian Ogden (thank you) answer specifically:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
```